# Bio.SwissProt.parse on swiss formatted in memory data in chunks

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I'd like to read in swiss data and get records in chunks instead of reading in the entire file.

So far, I've split the file into chunks as seen below

```
from io import StringIO

sprot_io = StringIO()

footer = b'CC   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------\n'
with gzip.open(response['Body'], "r") as f:
    for row in f:
        if row == footer:
            sprot_io.write(row.decode('utf-8'))
            <now parse the record>

            sprot_io = list()

        else:
            sprot_io.write(row.decode('utf-8'))
```

However, when I try to parse these chunks using Bio.SwissProt.parse, I get an unexpected end of file error

```
def parse_record(file):
    seq = next(SeqIO.parse(file, format='swiss'))
    return seq
```

I use next because the function is actually returning a generator, but I should only be getting one record anyway.

I'm assuming there is something wrong with the format I'm giving to it, but I haven't been able to figure out what could be going wrong from looking at the base code

https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/SwissProt/KeyWList.py

This is the file I'm trying to parse, but warning... it is roughly 3 gigs
ftp://ftp.uniprot.org/pub/databases/uniprot/current_release/knowledgebase/complete/uniprot_*.dat.gz

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I over complicated it by a lot. I ended up using smart-open to stream the data from s3, and then I passed that to the parser, which takes a ```<class '_io.BytesIOWrapper'>`` just fine.

```
import boto3
from smart_open import open
session = boto3.session()
tp = {'client': session.client('s3')}
handle = open(url, 'rt', transport_params=tp)

seqs = SeqIO.parse(handle, format='swiss')
record = next(seqs)
```